# Javascript array of objects undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, object

I am attempting to make an array of objects in javascript but when i try and print the array to the console (using chrome) all i get is undefine, unless i print the array just after the push.

```
 var subitems = [];
 for (var i = 1; i < 1000; i = i + 50) {
       $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' + username + '/subscriptions?max-results=50&start-index=' + i + '&alt=json', function (data) {
           var output = "";
           for (var x in data.feed.entry) {
               var subtitle = data.feed.entry[x].yt$username.$t;
               var subchannel = data.feed.entry[x].yt$channelId.$t;
               var subphoto = data.feed.entry[x].media$thumbnail.url;
               subitems.push({
                   subtitle: subtitle,
                   subchannel: subchannel,
                   subphoto: subphoto
               });
               console.log(subitems[0]); //Prints Fine
               output += '<div class="subtitle"><img src="' + subphoto + '"> <a href="http://www.youtube.com/channel/' + subchannel + '">' + propercase(subtitle) + '</a></div>';
           }
           maincontent.innerHTML = maincontent.innerHTML + output;
       });
 }
 console.log(subitems[0]); //This is undefined
```

Comment: Put console.log inside the getJSON function callback. Ajax as that is called is typically run asynchronously so the function can be called when ready, but the code immediately after the getJSON call gets run before that inner code is run. If it is done otherwise, it can lock up the page/interface.

Comment: Could it be possible that because xhr is asynchonous the subitems hasn't been set by the time you log it (when it's udefined)?

Comment: Additionally, I would avoid making *that* many Ajax calls at once.

Comment: @HMR yes it is because XHR is asynchonous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the "easier" way of doing this: count XHR requests and fire the done function when all requests have returned:

```
var xhrCount = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < 1000; i = i + 50) {
    xhrCount++; // increment before request
    $.getJSON('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' + username + '/subscriptions?max-results=50&start-index=' + i + '&alt=json', function (data) {
            // process response      
            // decrement after request is processed
            xhrCount--;
            if (xhrCount === 0) {
                // at this point all requests have returned  
                console.log(subitems);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update: a much better approach is to utilize [`jQuery.Deferred()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) object. A [quick demo is setup here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/2AALK/) which needs some fixes. The general idea is to keep a track of all AJAX requests you make, pass them over to `deferred.when()` and assign the done function using the `deferred.done()`. Code (trimmed down for readability):

```
var subitems = [];
var deferreds = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 1000; i = i + 50) {
    var deferred = $.getJSON('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/warnerbrospictures/uploads?max-results=50&start-index=' + i + '&alt=json', function (data) {
        for (var j = 0; j < data.feed.entry.length; j++) {
            subitems.push({
                title: data.feed.entry[j].title.$t
            });
        }
    });
    deferreds.push(deferred);
}
$.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function () {
    console.clear();
    console.log(subitems);
    for (var i = 0; i < subitems.length; i++) {
        console.log(subitems[i].title);
    }
});
```

Note: Google data feeds contain the total number of results so it is possible to eliminate the hard coded "1000".

Comment: why not just vote to close as the duplicate it is?

Comment: @JanDvorak: the duplicate is a good read. The recommended solution in that question to restructure code; I have explained how it could be done in this particular case.

Comment: I'm convinced that this answer could be incorporated into the duplicate. The dupe would surely benefit.

Answer (score -2):

Try declaring your array as:

```
var subitems = [{}];
```

Comment: That won't help. The declaration of the array is not the problem.

Comment: there's no reason to start the array with an extra empty object insid